# Validity of Propositional Logic

Tags: logic

I understand the whole process of validating propositional logic. However, for this following question, am not too sure of the compound propositions of each line

I am assuming

No fish are forgetful (~p)

Nobody but fish have scales (q)

--

Nobody forgetful has scales (~p => q)

is that right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those sentences don't sound like something one would use _propositional_ logic to model ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm it is in the exercise for PL, unfortunately so there must be some way this can be interpreted that I'm not getting

Comment: It is **not** *propositional logic*; it is an example of [Syllogism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/) (in modern term : *monadic predicate logic*) : "No F are P", "All S are F"; therefore : "No P are S".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see to shoehorn this into *propositional* logic would be to work with an *implicit* subject and let the propositional variables be:

- $S$ meaning "it has scales"
- $P$ meaning "it's forgetful"
- $M$ meaning "it's a fish"

in which case the reasoning could be written as

$$ \frac{\neg(M \land P) \qquad \qquad S\to M}{\neg(S\land P)} $$

which corresponds to the classical "Cellarent" sylogism, if we rephrase it slightly as:

- No fish is forgetful
- All things with scales are fish
- Therefore: Nothing that has scales is forgetful

---

In modern mathematical logic, however, it would be much more natural to express it in *predicate logic*, where the reasoning would look like

$$\frac{ \neg\exists x(M(x)\land P(x)) \qquad \qquad \neg\exists x(\neg M(x)\land S(x))}
{\neg\exists x(P(x)\land S(x))} $$

Answer (score 0):

This appears to require predicate logic to validate.

Can you provide some more background on where this question comes from? For example, if this is from a textbook, what section is it associated with? What are some other problems from that section? What are some sample solutions they provide, if any?

Comment: this was a question from my lecture notes on validity of propositional logic although it does start to look like it shouldn't belong there. No sample solutions.